# gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, node-gyp

I am trying to run the ionic project. on "npm install" command, I am getting python2 not found error. I guess something is wrong with my npm config file. 
Can anyone help me to find the solution.

```
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\MobileWorkspace\\old2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\MobileWorkspace\\old2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\MobileWorkspace\\old2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\MobileWorkspace\\old2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\MobileWorkspace\\old2\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\MobileWorkspace\\old2\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\MobileWorkspace\old2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\MobileWorkspace\\old2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\MobileWorkspace\\old2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\MobileWorkspace\\old2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\MobileWorkspace\\old2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\MobileWorkspace\\old2\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\MobileWorkspace\\old2\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```